# Angular 2 and something like *ngGet or *ngFind

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I want to find exactly one thing in an array and then somehow access it with a variable. Not looking for the method but how to write the template for this.

How can I achieve something like this?

```
<div *ngGet="let thisOneThing of findInThings(thingId)">
    <awesome-component [thisOneThing]="thisOneThing"></awesome-component>
</div>
```

Where the awesome-component template is that:

```
<div>{{ thisOneThing.someProperty }}</div>
```

So basically: Look into an array and find something, put it in a new variable and pass it to the component.

I know this seems similar to *ngFor BUT I don't want the constructor being called on the awesome-component when there is no such thing.

The following doesn't work because ng2 doesn't allow for 2 structural directives:

```
<div *ngFor="let thisOneThing of findInThings(thingId)" *ngIf="thisOneThing">
     ....
</div>
```

When I use  or  in the *ngFor, then nothing shows up.

Alternative:

```
<div *ngFor="let thisOneThing of findInThings(thingId)">
     <div *ngIf="thisOneThing">
         ....
     </div>
</div>
```

But *ngFor is not exactly what I want, I don't want to loop actually. (The whole piece lies actually already in two other loops and depending on how big the things array is, this would be causing performance issues)

There is the concept of pipes, and if possible I want to avoid additional files (I just have a little app and already close to 100 files) but you are more than welcome to propose a solution if that is the way to go here.

Looking forward to your ideas. Thank you.

**Update**

Storing something and use it in the controller is not an option here.

```
<div *ngFor="let day of allDaysInAYear">
    <div *ngFor="let hour of allHoursInOneDay">     

        <div *ngGetMeAVariable="let thisOneInterview of findInInterviews(day, hour)">

              <!-- here I have a separate componenent, to make it easy it's inline here. I want access thisOneInterview , something like -->
              <div>{{ thisOneInterview.nameOfApplicant }}</div>

         </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I guess I could just use ngFor around an ngIf (but then I need to use an iterable and write ugly ngIf with .length > 0 and pass thisOneThing[0]..)

Also as @jb-nizet suggested call the method two times. But is there a more beautiful solution where there is less overhead?

Comment: Why do you wan to to do all that from the template rather than the component code? When thingId changes, find thisOneThing in the component code, and initialize this.thisOneThing. In the template just use <awesome-component *ngIf="thisOneThing" [thisOneThing]="thisOneThing"></awesome-component>. If inding thisOneThing is fast enough, you can even just do <awesome-component *ngIf="findThisOneThing(thingId)" [thisOneThing]="findThisOneThing(thingId)"></awesome-component>

Comment: In the component code if have an array and I've got a function which finds me what I want but the question is how to access it and give it a variable in the template. I tried ngIf before but that threw an error. I'll try it again and provide an update here. Thanks so far.

Comment: Great, so that would work. Now it is not optimal that the same method is being called twice. That was one reason why I didn't choose that one previously. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: It's actually called more than twice. That's why I recommended to find thisOneThing and store it in a field every time thingId changes. But I don't know what thingId is, where it comes from, and when it changes. If you posted a complete minimal example of what you have, I could probably help more.

Comment: It's actually not a thingId, I used it to make things simpler. I'll add an update above to make things more clear.

Comment: Again, don't try doing everything from the view. I don't see why you couldn't do this loop, once, in the component, and, in the view, just use something like interviews[day][hour], or just create a an array of days, where each day has an array of hours, where each hour has an interview

Comment: I need to do it in the view because I am displaying the different divs. Or do I understand you wrong?